# Reason for code incompatibility between C++ 2003 and C++ 2011 when referencing enums

Tags: c++, c++11, c++03

I'm trying to incorporate a library that was compiled using C++ 2011 by its author (the -std=c++0x flag is set) into my own code which is compiled using C++ 2003. Thankfully, the library contains no typical C++ 2011 keywords like `auto`. There is, however, one compilation error when I try compiling it using C++ 2003.

There are three enums defined in lines 42, 49 and 55 of this header file:
https://github.com/venkatrn/improved-mha-planner/blob/master/sbpl/include/sbpl/planners/mha_planner.h. They are `MetaSearchType`, `PlannerType` and `MHAType` in the following snippet:

```
namespace mha_planner
{
  enum MetaSearchType
  {
    ROUND_ROBIN,
    META_A_STAR,
    DTS
  };

  enum PlannerType
  {
    IMHA,
    SMHA
  };

  enum MHAType
  {
    ORIGINAL,
    PLUS,
    FOCAL,
    UNCONSTRAINED,
    GBFS
  };
}

class MHAReplanParams: public ReplanParams
{
  public:
    MHAReplanParams(double allocated_time): ReplanParams(allocated_time)
  {
    inflation_eps = 1.0;
    anchor_eps = 1.0;
    use_anchor = true;
    meta_search_type = mha_planner::MetaSearchType::ROUND_ROBIN;
    planner_type = mha_planner::PlannerType::SMHA;
    mha_type = mha_planner::MHAType::PLUS;
  };
    double inflation_eps, anchor_eps;
    bool use_anchor;
    mha_planner::MetaSearchType meta_search_type;
    mha_planner::PlannerType planner_type;
    mha_planner::MHAType mha_type;
}; 

//other classes
}
```

These enums are then used in the constructor of the class `MHAReplanParams` in the same namespace and file in lines 73, 74 and 75 in the original code. When compiling under C++ 2003, I get an error saying `mha_planner::MetaSearchType::ROUND_ROBIN is not a valid class or namespace reference`. Compiling under C++ 2011 however, doesn't give any issues. I tried looking up some of the 'code breaking' differences between the two versions, but I couldn't spot anything that could result in this.

Note: The reason I'm trying to stick with C++ 2003 is that I'm using other, larger libraries more extensively that are intended for 2003, and I've heard that sometimes "bad things happen" when you try to mix code intended for C++ 2011 with that targeting older versions.

Comment: Don't link out to code, just post code.

Comment: If ABIs mismatch, all bets are off. Is there any documentation by Microsoft that specifically says you can mix binaries across these compilers? Have you made sure to stick with a C ABI?

Comment: So, you talk about particular versions of the C++ standard, but you aren't talking about what your compiler is.  The other libraries -- what is their interface?

Comment: I'm using a build system called `catkin` which is the official one for the Robot Operating System (ROS): http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/conceptual_overview. The library I'm trying to incorporate was initially compiled using `rosbuild`, which is an earlier build system for ROS.

Comment: Your new compiler was no doubt affected by the addition of `enum class` to C++11.  You'll have to replace mha_planner::MetaSearchType::ROUND_ROBIN with mha_planner::ROUND_ROBIN

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks! That fixed it

Comment: in C++11, `enum class` creates a namespace-like scope into which the enum values are injected.  In C++03, all `enum`s only injected their enum values into the surrounding namespace scope.  Many compilers now inject non-`enum class` enum value names into a scope named after the enum.  I cannot recall if the standard requires, or forbids, that for non-`enum class`es.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe (but am not 100% sure) that before C++11, you couldn't use the name of the enum type itself as a qualifier.

In other words, `mha_planner::MetaSearchType::ROUND_ROBIN` is allowed in C++11, but in earlier versions, the enum value is just at the enclosing namespace scope, so you'd write `mha_planner::ROUND_ROBIN` instead.